# Removing background image with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have a `div` with a `background-image`. When a button is clicked this **image** needs to fade away (and fade in again when another button is pressed). So only the `background-image` should fade, not the content.

**How can I achieve this effect?** I have tried jQuery's `animate()`, but that does not seem to work. I cannot get CSS transitions to work either, also `opacity` seems to make all the content transparent too.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzLg37rp/)

Comment: This seems easy enough to solve. Could you show us what you already have?

Comment: Have you tried targeting the background element associated with the div element, and using the click () function combined with fadeOut() (and possibly fadeIn())?

Comment: @MathBio I think my question was unclear, I have clarified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way you would be able to fade a background image is to put it in a seperate div and fade that:

```js
$('.fade').on('click', function() {
  $('.background').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/city/1/) left top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id diam ac dolor gravida ultricies. Sed pretium, orci at pharetra placerat, velit mauris posuere mauris, et ornare libero ligula tristique enim. Etiam vitae lobortis erat, ut volutpat ipsum.
  Suspendisse potenti.
</div>
<div class="fade">fade toggle</div>
```

**Update**

You can use a css transition too fading to a transparent png:

```js
$('.background').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blank')
})
```

```css
.background {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city/1/) left top no-repeat;
  transition: background-image 0.5s;
}

.background.blank {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/qkeOXbO.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">

</div>
```

Comment: That is a nice way too, although CSS3 `transition` has less browser support, so I prefer the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I would create a new div that holds your background image. Then apply the fade on the element.

I have created a fiddle for you to see https://jsfiddle.net/bx0dt60a/

JS snippet below

```js
$('#fadeOut').click(function(){
 $('#background').fadeOut(500);
});

$('#fadeIn').click(function(){
 $('#background').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id"container" class="container">
  <div id="background" class="background"></div>
</div>

<div id="fadeOut">
  fade out
</div>
<div id="fadeIn">
  fade in
</div>
```